# Error 1004 when setting Range.Locked

Tags: excel, vba

I get the catch-all runtime error 1004, "unable to set the Locked property of the Range class" when, well, trying to set the [`Locked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213550%28v=office.12%29.aspx) property of a Range object. The code looks like this:

```
that_goddamn_sheet.Unprotect

; Determine if we should proceed

that_goddamn_range.Locked = True

; Do more stuff

that_goddamn_sheet.Protect
```

When I set a breakpoint on the line and try to query the value of `that_goddamn_range.Locked` from the Immediate window, this works without problem, but setting it fails.

If, however, I run `that_goddamn_range.Select`, break the macro, unprotect the sheet (it gets reprotected automatically on selection change) then right click, pick Properties, switch to the Protection tab and tick Locked then confirm, things work okay however.

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: What's the text of the error message?

Comment: @Tim Good point, included in the question.

Answer (score 23):

Here’s a complete explanation:

Typically, there are two causes of this error: trying to change a cell’s **Locked** property on a protected sheet and/or trying to change the **Locked** property of a single cell in a merged range.

In the first case, you can either unlock the sheet or set **UserInterfaceOnly** protection for it, which is highly recommended since you then don’t have to mess with repeatedly unlocking/locking it.

With regard to merged cells, you can’t lock a single cell that is part of a merged range but there are reasonable options:

- If you are using cell-address notation to reference the cell/range,

  `Range("A1").Locked = True`

  then reference the whole merged range instead:

  `Range("A1:A3").Locked = True    'where "A1:A3" is the entire merged range`
- If you are using a named range for a set of merged cells, by default it will be defined to reference the first of the merged cells only. You can either edit its definition to include the entire merged range or use its **MergeArea** property to reference its associated merged range:

  `Range(“SomeNamedRange”).MergeArea.Locked = True`

  But note that you can’t do both since the **MergeArea** property is, apparently, undefined for a range that is not a strict *subset* of a larger merged area!
- Of course, you can always unmerge the merged range before setting the Locked property of an included cell and then re-merge it afterward, but I have never seen a situation in which one of the above two solutions wasn’t sufficient (and much cleaner).

Comment: A note to add to this comprehensive answer is that, for a given range or a named range that contains a set of addresses, you will need to loop through the cells and rebuild that given range to contain all merged areas of all those cells, then you can set the locked property in one go using `NewlyBuiltRange.Locked = True`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot lock a cell that is part of a range of merged cells unless it is the upper-left corner cell. The following works for any cell or merged area of cells.

```
Sub LockCells()
   Dim R As Range
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect
   Cells.Locked = False
   For Each R In Range("A1", Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address)
      If R.MergeArea.Range("A1").Address = R.Address And R.HasFormula Or IsText(R) Then
         R.MergeArea.Locked = True
      End If
   Next
   ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub

Function IsText(What) As Boolean
   IsText = False
   On Error Resume Next
   IsText = (CDbl(What) <> What)
   If Err.Number Then IsText = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

> [the sheet] gets reprotected automatically on selection change

The sheet, for some reason, reprotected itself *in the middle of the method*. Unprotecting it again immediately before to the setting of the `Locked`property fixed my issue.

I actually had multiple ranges that I needed to lock in a row, and had to unprotect the sheet before every single property change.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried to hide manually the cells, and receive the following warning:
`Cannot shift objects off sheet.`

My problem was some comments in cells of the same sheet. After remove all the comments of the sheet, the code runs.

My code find the row using match case in a Column used only for this (because I need to insert some rows and the Column "B" is my reference to identify the row).

My Code :

```
Rows((WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Range("B:B"), 0)) - 1 & ":" & (WorksheetFunction.Match(13, Range("B:B"), 0)) + 15).EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue. Turned out the user had filtered data and then saved it and protection can't be changed on a filtered data set without turning the filters off.