# Cannot set Locked-property despite UserInterFaceOnly=True and no merged cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am setting the `Locked` property of a small range, but the code fails with the familiar `1004 cannot set the Locked property of the Range class`, similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9184818/4604845).

- The range in question does not contain any merged cells
- My sheet is locked with `UserInterFaceOnly=True`

I am out of ideas - how can I find out what is causing this to fail?

EDIT: I failed to mention that I am locking the sheet, saving it, closing and re-opening - and the code for setting the `Locked`-property is triggered in `Workbook_Open`.

This leads to a design issue caused by the fact that re-opening the workbook [removes the interface-only protection, leaving the entire sheet protected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38375298/4604845). Thanks to @CLR for putting me on that path, and credit goes to him if he decides to submit it as an answer.

Lock code:

```
Sub LockSheet()
    If ws1.ProtectContents = False Then ws1.Protect Password:="1", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

Code snippet that fails when the sheet is protected (but works if I unprotect the sheet):

```
With summaryRange
    .Locked = Not (someBoolVar) ' <-- 1004 Cannot set Locked etc.
    .FormulaHidden = Not (someBoolVar)
End With
```

where summaryRange is qualified and working in other parts of the code:

```
Set summaryRange = ws1.Range(firstSummaryColumn & "4:" & lastSummaryColumn & lastRow)
```

& also verified working by the compiler:

```
? Module1.summaryRange.Address
$J$4:$M$50
```

Comment: I know it seems counter-intuitive, but whenever I protect with `UserInterFaceOnly:=True`, I make sure I **remove** any existing protection first.Seems to fix most of the UserInterFaceOnly issues I get..

Comment: You definitely don't need brackets in this expression `= Not (someBoolVar)`. That's not causing your problems though.

Comment: @CallumDA Thank you for the input. I am aware it's not required, t's just a habit :)

Comment: Yeah, I spotted the check, it's just that when a file is saved, the `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` is removed and if you attempt to reset it while the sheet is protected without it you get no warning at all, it just ignores the request.

Comment: `UserInterfaceOnly` gets removed?? As in, practically the same as set to `False`?

Comment: That's my understanding, yes. A file saved with that flag when reopened is opened without it. I've seen many Workbooks that on `Workbook.Open` remove any protection and reapply with the `UserInterfaceOnly`. I've also seen this done in `Workbook.Activate` but never really understood why. There are lots of questions in SO re `UserInterfaceOnly`.

Comment: For what it's worth... It's actually a bad habit to have in VBA. Putting brackets around something forces a call to its default member so something like `Set rng = (Range("A1:A2"))` would throw an error *just because of the brackets*.

Comment: Learning all kinds of things today. I'm using `Workbook_ Open` to trigger the code in question, so if `UserInterFaceOnly` is stripped, I guess that puts a giant wrench in my plan to not have to remove and reapply the lock when the workbook opens... and I also was not aware that brackets can lead to errors. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your problem and can't, using the below subs to mimic your code.

Sheet protection:

```
Sub LockSheet()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If ws1.ProtectContents = False Then
        ws1.Protect Password:="1", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Else
        ws1.Unprotect Password:="1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Range locking:

```
Sub lockit()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim someBoolVar As Boolean
    someBoolVar = True
    Dim summaryRange As Range
    Set summaryRange = ws1.Range("$J$4:$M$50")

    With summaryRange
        .Locked = Not someBoolVar ' <-- No error triggered here
        .FormulaHidden = Not someBoolVar
    End With        
End Sub
```

Possible causes:

- Your `summaryRange` is not properly defined: you have debunked this in your Q.
- Something fishy is happening with the sheet locking: I have debunked this above.
- Your `someBoolVar` is not properly defined. Note in my above code, I have defined `someBoolVar` as `True`, and the code works. Try debugging `?someBoolVar` in the immediate window to see what it is before it is used. Edit: you have debunked this too.

---

Edit:

As suggested in the comments, your issue is probably that the `UserInterfaceOnly` flag gets reset to `False` when the workbook is closed. To sidestep this, you will have to re-apply the protection when the workbook opens. This sub will achieve that:

```
Sub reprotect()
' Called from the Workbook_Open event
    ' Cycle through sheets
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' If protected, reprotect to reset UserInterfaceOnly flag
        If sh.ProtectContents = True Then
            sh.Unprotect Password:="1"
            sh.Protect Password:="1", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        End If
    Next sh
End Sub
```

Fortunately, the `Locked` property of ranges is not affected by the workbook being closed, so you will not have to re-apply that condition again!

The Office VBA documentation doesn't address this problem, but the [VB documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.protect(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) (often comparable) in fact does:

> If you apply this method with the UserInterfaceOnly argument set to true and then save the workbook, **the entire worksheet (not just the interface) will be fully protected when you reopen the workbook**. To re-enable the user interface protection after the workbook is opened, you must again apply this method with UserInterfaceOnly set to true.

Comment: I inserted a `Debug.Print` statement (the routine the code runs in is called from `Workbook_Open` and this was the only reliable way of getting to the variable before any other code has had its run at it) and the boolean evaluates just fine (to `True`). Additionally, I tried replacing the variable with a static `True` and had the same result.

Comment: This sounds like a niche problem then, please add an edit to your question including the full relevant section of the `Workbook_Open` sub so it can be tested properly. Do you have the same problem if you use my code exactly?

Comment: I edited my post a bit ago (no code for `Workbook_Open` as it just calls a `Sub` from Module1 and it's inside Module1 the failure happens), and another commenter may have discovered what the problem is (closing and re-opening the workbook seems to remove `UserInterFaceOnly=True`).

Comment: Ah yes, I remember now that I've had the same problem in the past! See my edit for more information :)