# How do I fix error 1004 in vba excel when trying to unlock some cells?

Tags: vba, excel, locking

I know that there are already a bunch of threads on error 1004, but after digging through them I haven't found a situation similar to mine. I'm trying to lock a workbook except for a range of cells, using the info I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037400/how-to-lock-the-data-in-a-cell-in-excel-using-vba) and the following code:

```
If SecurityActive= "yes" Then
    Worksheets("Invullen").Range("D7, D9, D11, D15, D17, D19, D23, J12, J14:J16").Locked = False

    'INVULLEN
    Worksheets("Invullen").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'AFDRUKKEN
    Worksheets("Afdrukken").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'AFDRUKKENBEFR
    Worksheets("AfdrukkenBEfr").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'BENL
    Worksheets("BEnl").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'BEFR
    Worksheets("BEfr").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'NL
    Worksheets("NL").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'FR
    Worksheets("FR").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'UK
    Worksheets("UK").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'DE
    Worksheets("DE").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    'TECHNISCH
    Worksheets("Technisch").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End If
```

SecurityActive is a variable I use to be able to quickly change wether I want to secure the workbook or not. The error highlights the second line of the code. Does anyone how to fix the error?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `.Locked` state **after** Protecting the Worksheet?

Comment: Yes. It did not work.

Comment: You are using `.Range` in wrong way. E.g. instead of `.Range("D7, D9")` use `Application.Union(.Range("D7"), .Range("D9"))`. Read about `Range` and `Union` in help files.

Comment: Are you sure there are no typos in your worksheet names? What is the exact error message? @EganWolf His Range method works fine, that's not the issue.

Comment: EganWolf your suggestion didn't work. My code returns the same error when I only try to unlock one cell, so that shouldn't be the problem. @Peh I'm sure there are there are no typos in the worksheet names. The exact error message is:


    `Fout 1004 tijdens uitvoering:
    Door de toepassing of door object gedefinieerde fout`

Which translates to something like:

    `Runtime error 1004:
    Error defined by the application or the object`

That's not an exact translation though.

Comment: Are you sure the sheet is unprotected before? And any possibility that there is more than one open workbook? If so try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invullen")` to specify the correct workbook.

Comment: @Peh I verified that the sheet had no protection. I have only one workbook open, and trying `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invullen")` doesn't work.

Comment: @EganWolf the reference to `.Range("D7, D9")` works fine in VBA.
@BartVos (Goedendag!) You need to have the sheet unprotected before you can alter the locked state of cells.

Comment: That's odd on an unprotected sheet your code works fine for me without issues.

Comment: @Peh Well after clicking away the error message I can edit any cell on the worksheet, so that should mean the worksheet was unprotected right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime 1004 will be thrown while trying to alter cell properties while the sheet is still protected.

Use:

```
Worksheets("Invullen").Unprotect
Worksheets("Invullen").Range("D7, D9, D11, D15, D17, D19, D23, J12, J14:J16").Locked = False
'... Other stuff
Worksheets("Invullen").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

etc.

Since Excel 2016 the runtime error 1004 is more specific than until 2010.
With protection on it'll throw "1004 Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class."

**Edit:** This error also get's thrown when one or more cells in the address range are merged cells.

Comment: this returns the same error, on the same piece of code.

Comment: Hm strange. Runs perfectly here. Can you provide full code?

Comment: See edit. It also errors on merged ranges. You need to reference the entire merged range. More extensive answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184818/error-1004-when-setting-range-locked)

Comment: What would be the best way to do that? Is there a place where I can upload my full excelsheet?

Comment: That works great! Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @RikSportel Nice, that you figured out that there were merged cells within the range.