# Can't assign property Locked from the class Range

Tags: excel, vba

I've been protecting my sheet from changes and suddenly it's telling me that property `Locked` cannot be assigned and I've seen that the methods from `Range` don't seem to work, but it's only in this file. Please help me.

```
Sub Protecion()
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Unprotect
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Cells.Locked = True
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Range("D6:F28,K5:M34,R7:V14,T15:U17,Y5:AB16,AE12,AE14,AE15,AG6:AG12,AG15,AK5:AK12,AP4:AR6,B6:B27,AH15,B33:B54,M5:M34").Locked = False
    Sheets(Sheets.Count - 1).Protect
End Sub
```

Comment: Are there any merged cells in the above range?

Comment: Which line is failing? `...Locked = True` or `...Locked = False`?

Comment: Try to do this manually in excel and see if excel gives you a reason why you cannot do it. Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184818/error-1004-when-setting-range-locked)